# Voice to text on Tablets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, html

I am developing an html5 app using IntelXDK. Part of the app is to have the functionality of speech to text.

I have tried using the webkitSpeechRecognition which works fine on web but when I tried it on tablet (which has microphone) it does not.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea id="textarea" rows=10 cols=80></textarea>
 <button id="button" onclick="toggleStartStop()"></button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var recognizing;
 var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
 recognition.continuous = true;
 reset();
 recognition.onend = reset();

 recognition.onresult = function (event) {
   for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
     if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
       textarea.value += event.results[i][0].transcript;
     }
   }
 }

 function reset() {
   recognizing = false;
   button.innerHTML = "Click to Speak";
 }

 function toggleStartStop() {
   if (recognizing) {
     recognition.stop();
     reset();
   } else {
     recognition.start();
     recognizing = true;
     button.innerHTML = "Click to Stop";
   }
 }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What solution would you recommend?

Comment: do you have google chrome installed on your tablet

Comment: It won't be visible on google chrome but it would be like an app

Comment: i guess..webkit uses google chrome to perform speech to text..i read here http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2014/01/javascript/using-the-web-speech-api-to-control-a-html5-video..so if chrome is not there may be it will not work

Comment: Chrome is there but this app is not visible by typing a url but by opening an app. It is developed by html5 but compiled as an app

Comment: No one knows the solution? :S